# using checkbox to select and delete row from gridiew datasource = session C# .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, gridview

I have been searching on here and other sites for three days for a solution.  I need to select one or more rows (using checkbox) and delete selected row(s) from a gridview who's datasource is a session datatable as you will see.  Not interested in SQLConnections or LINQ Entities.  As a result I am not sure if I need to use e.commandarguments, or how to go about it, but I have tried them with no luck.

Error is visible and clearly commented on CART.ASPX.CS page inside the following method

if (chkRemCart != null && chkRemCart.Checked)

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated and if you require any further coding or explanations to help with a solution, just ask.
Thank you in advance.

CART.ASPX

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCart" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" CellPadding="4"
        HeaderStyle-CssClass="header" EmptyDataText="You have successfully cleared your Shopping Cart"
        OnRowDataBound="gvCart_RowDataBound"  >
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Movie Selector">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRemCart" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Movie ID">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblMovieID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MovieId") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Duration">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDuration" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Duration") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Genre">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblGenre" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Genre") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rating">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblRating" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Rating") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Price","{0:n}") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:Button ID="btnRem" runat="server" OnClick="RemCart" Text="Remove Selection" CssClass="button" Title="Remove Movies From Cart" />
```

CART.ASPX.CS

Page_Load calling RefreshPages() method.  gvCart displaying all columns and rows of items in Datasource/Session/Datatable

```
    public void RefreshPages()
    {
        if (Session["SelectedMovies"] != null)
        {
            DataTable MovieTable = (DataTable)Session["SelectedMovies"];
            gvCart.DataSource = MovieTable;
            gvCart.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void RemCart(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Check session exists 
        if (Session["selectedMovies"] != null)
        {
            // Opening / Retreiving DataTable.
            DataTable MovieTable = (DataTable)Session["SelectedMovies"];

            foreach (GridViewRow row in gvCart.Rows)
            {
                CheckBox chkRemCart = row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkRemCart") as CheckBox;

                if (chkRemCart != null && chkRemCart.Checked)
                {
                    //  Error appearing on line below.  Scroll right to read.
                    int MovieId = Convert.ToInt32(gvCart.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value); // Error here. //Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non - negative and less than the size of the collection. 

                    MovieTable.Rows.RemoveAt(row.RowIndex);

                    //Saving session
                    Session["selectedMovies"] = MovieTable;
                    // Updating gvCart
                    gvCart.DataSource = MovieTable;
                    gvCart.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign  DataKeyNames="PrimaryKey" in gridview like below and check

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvCart" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"  DataKeyNames="MovieId" CellPadding="4"
        HeaderStyle-CssClass="header" EmptyDataText="You have successfully cleared your Shopping Cart"
        OnRowDataBound="gvCart_RowDataBound"  >
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Movie Selector">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRemCart" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Movie ID">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblMovieID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MovieId") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Duration">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDuration" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Duration") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Genre">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblGenre" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Genre") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rating">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblRating" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Rating") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Price","{0:n}") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

code behind:

```
public void RefreshPages()
        {
            if (Session["SelectedMovies"] != null)
            {
                DataTable MovieTable = (DataTable)Session["SelectedMovies"];
                gvCart.DataSource = MovieTable;
                gvCart.DataBind();
            }
        }

    protected void RemCart(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Check session exists 
        if (Session["selectedMovies"] != null)
        {
            // Opening / Retreiving DataTable.
            DataTable MovieTable = (DataTable)Session["SelectedMovies"];

            foreach (GridViewRow row in gvCart.Rows)
            {
                CheckBox chkRemCart = row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkRemCart") as CheckBox;

                if (chkRemCart != null && chkRemCart.Checked)
                {
                    //  Error appearing on line below.  Scroll right to read.
                    int MovieId = Convert.ToInt32(gvCart.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value); // Error here. //Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non - negative and less than the size of the collection. 

                    DataRow[] drs = dt.Select("MovieId = '" + MovieId + "'"); // replace with your criteria as appropriate

                    if (drs.Length > 0)
                    {
                        MovieTable.Rows.Remove(drs[0]);
                    }
                }
            }
            //Saving session
            Session["selectedMovies"] = MovieTable;
            // Updating gvCart
            gvCart.DataSource = MovieTable;
            gvCart.DataBind();
        }
    }
```